# Google maps api will not return coordinates on submit

Tags: php, maps, submit

I try to describe my issue as easy as possible.. 
When I submit a form, I need to call another function. I tried onSubmit, but unfortunately it doesnot work properly, as the function that I need to call is Google Maps API matter getting coordinates from textbox where a user is choosing the location.. The function is never called or it seems that it is called too late.. So I tried this:

```
<input type="button" value="Search" name="submitBtn" id="subBtn1" onclick="onSubmit1();">
```

and function onSubmit1() is as following:

```
function onSubmit1 () {
    codeAddress();
//   document.forms["searchForm"].submit();
 }
```

After clicking the button, the function works.. codeAddress gets me the latitude and longitude from Google servers and pre-fills them to textboxes in my searchForm.

However, if I remove the doble slash and want to submit the form, the following happens:

form is submitted, but the latitude and longitude is always empty strings..

Any ideas.. Is it possible, that the second line in onSubmit1 function just doesnot wait for goole to do its job?

Thanks for any tips..

Please know, that the form and all its functions work perfectly if I for example set the coordinates by myself and submit the form then.. There is no problem in that

EDIT

```
function codeAddress() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById("my-address").value;
    geocoder.geocode( 
        { 'address': address}, 
        function(results, status) { 
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
                var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                document.getElementById("my-lat").value = lat;
                document.getElementById("my-lng").value = lng; 
            } else { 
                 //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            } 
        }); 
}
```

Comment: Please show the definition of `codeAddress()` function. my **guess** is that ist an asynchronous function that returns immediately.

Comment: function codeAddress() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById("my-address").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var lat =  results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      var lng =  results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    document.getElementById("my-lat").value = lat;
      document.getElementById("my-lng").value = lng;
      } 

      else {
        //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }

Comment: Hi, thanks for fast reply.. I dont find how to format the function properly, so the post doesnot look like mess, sorry

Comment: No problem, i edited your question with the correct formatting, plus provided an answer

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that codeAddress is asynchronous (well the geocode method of the geocoder object is), and therefor returns immediately.

What you must do is only submit the form in the async callback:

```
function codeAddress() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById("my-address").value;
    geocoder.geocode( 
        { 'address': address}, 
        function(results, status) { 
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
                var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                document.getElementById("my-lat").value = lat;
                document.getElementById("my-lng").value = lng; 
                //now submit form
                document.forms["searchForm"].submit();
            } else { 
                 //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            } 
        }); 
}
```

Comment: Man!, YOu are great, you should change your status to LEGENDARY.. Many thanks..!!

Comment: i would like to, but I am totaly new here and need to get reputation points.. I do that once i get them

Comment: OK, thanks. You should be able to accept an answer after a short period of time (not sure how long, but its minutes) regardless of rep.